# Slitherlink: Around the W0rld

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, seasonal, humor, slitherlink

**Rules of Slitherlink**:

- Connect adjacent dots with vertical or horizontal lines to make a single loop.
- The numbers indicate how many lines surround it, while empty cells may be surrounded by any number of lines.
- The loop never crosses itself and never branches off.

---

[image]

Comment: [Link to Penpa version](https://git.io/JYVqv) (let me know if there's a mistake, I transcribed this manually)

Comment: Haha! I had a feeling the [tag:seasonal] tag was going to prove appropriate here! :)

Comment: @Stiv yeap, adding the tag :)

Comment: An alternative (and perhaps superior?) version of the joke involves a rot13(yratgu fvk ybbc fheebhaqvat gjb guerr pyhrf) :)

Comment: @happystar yes!! I once found it published by someone and I was dumbfounded :))

Comment: Daft Punk would love this puzzle. https://youtube.com/watch?v=LKYPYj2XX80

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is (drumroll please...)

> [image: around_the_w0rld_sol]
>  Yep, that's it. All those clues for just a measly square. (I guess that's why this puzzle's tagged [humor](/questions/tagged/humor)!)

**Explanation:**

We start by

> marking the edges where the loop cannot pass through due to the 0 clues:
>  [image: around_the_w0rld_1]

Next,

> we progressively mark off edges coming off of dots where the other three edges (two for a border dot, one for a corner dot) coming off of them are marked as unusable. We continue to do this until we reach a state like this - note the square at R10C16:
>  [image: around_the_w0rld_2]

And here's the coup de grâce:

> It appears that we're able to make a connected loop spanning the entirety of the grid, but actually **we can't (!)** due to the edge marked with the star below not being usable:
>  [image: around_the_w0rld_3]
>  Thus, we are forced to use the square mentioned earlier for our loop, giving us our final solution.

Comment: Nicely done and well explained! XD

Comment: @athin Thanks, this is a *really* nice construction!